# Apply a function to each element of a vector, avoiding using for loop

Tags: matlab

I have a vector `x = [10,20,30,40]` in Matlab, now I would like to apply `y = rand(m,1)` to each element in `x`, i.e generating:

```
y1 = rand(x(1),1);
y2 = rand(x(2),1);
y3 = rand(x(3),1);
y4 = rand(x(4),1);
```

The straight-forward way is to apply a `for` loop, but as we know that, `for` loop is not efficient in Matlab. So is that any other way to do that?

Follow-ups:
Applying a function to each element in vector in Matlab seems a very common problem, how can we handle such cases and avoid using `for` loop?

Comment: What's wrong with `for` loops? They haven't been a problem since MATLAB introduced the JIT compiler, and are often the most efficient answer. Have you profiled your code to see if the loop is the bottleneck? Also, I hope you're putting your data into a single cell array using `y{i}` rather than creating new variables on each iteration.

Comment: No, `for` loops are not necessarily slow for everything. Depends on what you are doing and here it is pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

create a random vector (ys)  it's size is sum of x elements then define a function to  extract each y with index:

```
x=[10,20,30,40];
s = sum(x);
c = cumsum(x);
ys = rand(s, 1);
y = @(i) ys(c(i)-x(i) +1:c(i)) ;
%%%%example
y(3)
y(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to point out the obvious. You imply that `y` would be a numerical array, but this is impossible, because each element has a different size. (e.g. y1 is 10x1, but y2 is 20x1)

Therefore, the only output that makes sense here is if you expect `y` to be a *cell* array.

You can very straightforwardly use `arrayfun` (or `cellfun` etc) to do this:

```
>> x = [10, 20, 30, 40]
>> f = @(a) {rand(a, 1)};  % output is a "cell" element
>> y = arrayfun(f, x); % apply 'f' to each element of x: returns a 1x4 cell array
```